# Connect:Direct syntax on IBM z/OS Mainframe

Tags: parsing, mainframe, connect-direct

I am writing a C# program to parse a Connect:Direct file and extract from it source and destination information.

I am not very fluent with Mainframe code. In particular, I am trying to understand the syntax of the destination Windows path.  The following is my interpretation but there are holes that I want to fill in order to write a parser that is able to handle any valid syntax variation that I may encounter.

The backslash character must be an escape character, so that two backslashes represent one. However the concatenation operation, || , seems to throw a monkey wrench in that. I presume that the slash character is the line continuation character. The quoted path also is enclosed with a backslash on each side. I'm not sure what this indicates. I'm guessing that it may mean that the enclosed string contains escape characters, suggesting that two backslashes should equal one.

```
NDMHGM30 PROCESS  SNODE=MYSNODE PACCT='G,HG1'                  -
 &SUBS=SUBSYS(ESP2)                                                 -
 &DMNDH=ESPM2D.DEMANDH                                              -
 &APPL=APPL(STHG102M.0)
STEP1  COPY FROM (PNODE DSN=GIO.HG1.CDB.ACCTEXT.T1(0)               -
               DISP=SHR)                                            -
       COMPRESS EXT                                                 -
       TO (SNODE                                                    -
 DSN=\'\\\\MyServerName\\IMDATA\\CLASS_SOURCE\\SYSTEM_INPUTS\   ||  -
     \\\CDB\\ACCOUNT.TXT'\                                      -
       SYSOPTS="STRIP.BLANKS(NO)"                                   -
               DISP=RPL)
   IF ( STEP1=0 ) THEN
STEP1A   RUN TASK (PGM=ESP,                                         -
 PARM=("&SUBS NOSTACK;AJ USERREQ.GHG30GOD &APPL COMPLETE;END"))
    ELSE
STEP1B   RUN TASK (PGM=ESP,                                         -
 PARM=("&SUBS NOSTACK;TR &DMNDH USER1('GHG30BAD');END"))
   EIF
```

Any wrong assumptions so far?

Given that, I would expect that the above path would be invalid because it would be interpreted as

```
\\MyServerName\IMDATA\CLASS_SOURCE\SYSTEM_INPUTS\\CDB\ACCOUNT.TXT
```

In other words, there would be an extra backslash in one of the levels. But I know that the Connect Direct works and correctly interprets the path as

```
\\MyServerName\IMDATA\CLASS_SOURCE\SYSTEM_INPUTS\CDB\ACCOUNT.TXT
```

How does the concatenation operator and/or line continuation impact the number of slashes that are needed here? What other syntax variables might also be valid that would result in the same valid Windows path?

Comment: Sorry, just noticed in my answer, and fixed, that SO-formatting needs a bit of breaking and escaping :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation (*IBM Sterling Connect:Direct for z/OS User Guide*):

> Special Purpose Bracketing
>
> You must often maintain special characters as part of a string. To
>   maintain special characters, enclose the string in bracketing
>   characters. Bracketing characters are backslashes (\), single
>   quotation marks ('), and double quotation marks (").
>
> Bracketing backslashes are indicators of special processing of a
>   character string.
>
> Sterling Connect:Direct does not maintain them as part of the string
>   at its final resolution. Use bracketing backslashes to:
>
> 1 Continue a string containing special characters across multiple
>   lines
>
> 2 Ensure that quotation marks within the string are maintained
>
> The following is an example of using bracketing backslashes in a
>   command: PACCT=\’DEPT\MIS\ || - 
>  \602’\
>
> Sterling Connect:Direct resolves the command as follows:
>
> PACCT=’DEPT\MIS602’

Combine that with this reference (*Sterling Connect:Direct for Microsoft Windows System Guide* - it is probably also detailed elsewhere in the *Windows* documentation for Connect:Direct)

> Microsoft Windows Services treats a backslash (\) as an escape
>   character, so type two backslashes for each backslash in the file
>   path.

The line you want to understand is this:

```
 DSN=\'\\\\MyServerName\\IMDATA\\CLASS_SOURCE\\SYSTEM_INPUTS\   ||  -
     \\\CDB\\ACCOUNT.TXT'\
```

On each of those two lines, the first and last backslashes (\) are for this reason:

> Continue a string containing special characters across multiple lines

and

> Sterling Connect:Direct does not maintain them as part of the string at its final resolution

Sterling Connect:Direct will resolve it to this:

```
 DSN='\\\\MyServerName\\IMDATA\\CLASS_SOURCE\\SYSTEM_INPUTS\\CDB\\ACCOUNT.TXT'
```

*Windows* will be presented with

```
 \\\\MyServerName\\IMDATA\\CLASS_SOURCE\\SYSTEM_INPUTS\\CDB\\ACCOUNT.TXT'
```

And *Windows* will then do its escape-processing, giving you this:

```
 \\MyServerName\IMDATA\CLASS_SOURCE\SYSTEM_INPUTS\CDB\ACCOUNT.TXT
```

This particular use of the backslash (\) is due to the presence of the continuation character (the - as the last character on the line) and the presence of special characters (what those are is listed in the documentation), not due to the use of the concatenation (||) (which, for information, is whatever symbol in the character-set you are using is X'4F', which is not necessarily the | symbol).

All the *Sterling Connect:Direct* documentation, for all platforms, is freely available from IBM's Information Centre, either usable directly online or downloadable as PDFs. Your choice. Just pick your favourite search-engine, and find the documentation for your versions of the product.